# Calculating total current requirement for LED matrix

Tags: current, led-matrix

So I am creating a LED matrix of 3072 RGB leds.

Each colour has a forward current of 10mA

I plan to split this into smaller matrices, something like 4x 16x48 matrices.

I also plan to multiplex these LEDs, I need the illusion that all LEDs are on at one time.

I don't need a massive refresh rate as I will never show video or even images. I will also never have any LED show white.

Im struggling to calculate the total current requirement for the project.

Some sources say counter for all LEDs be on at the same time (Which surely will never be the case)

Some say half the total of all LEDs, some say half.

Some say counter for 10mA per column and row.

So I am left a massive difference in answers such as:
92A
46A
23A
or 3.84 which even for someone with limited electronic knowledge seems an incredible low estimate.

Comment: Do you have any of the LEDs? If yes, power them up. Are they bright enough? Calculate the current you need for the brightness you want, not what 'some say'. If not, get some, and do some real homework!

Comment: if you split that into 16 row maticces then the peak current theough the led will need to be 160mA,  can they handle that?

Comment: The LED's will not look right if you drive them all with the same current. The red needs very little current. The green needs a lot, and the blue needs only a little. I think you need to get some LED's, set the white balance how you like it by adjusting all three LED's separately, then design your power supply so it can handle all LED's on at the same time. It is not rocket science.

Comment: I could power the LEDs up, find a brightness I like and measure the current. I will still be none the wiser. 
I plan to multiplex (which I didn't mention in my answer so I can see why I got the down vote, I'll now update it) it is because of the multiplexing I do not understand the current requirements.

Comment: It isn't going to matter. If you illuminate the LED's only part of the time, you will have to compensate by driving them with more current.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going static, 3072 LEDs for each color is 9216 LEDs, and if you want to render white and each LED takes 10 milliamperes, that's 9216 LEDs times 10 milliamperes, which comes out to about 92 amperes.

If you'll never want to render white and your LED array is multiplexed, then it's all just guesswork.

Comment: Im never going to be displaying white, however I will be mixing colours. I will only need a hundred or so different colours.

I do plan to have the display multiplexed.

Comment: 1.)Just for grins, let's say you have a single RGB triad/pixel and you want to display only six colors:  red,  orange, yellow, green, blue, and violet.  How are you  planning on accomplishing that? 2.) What will be the  the 3072 LED array's  update rate ?

Answer (score 2):

A good approximation for the maximum is to take the current that makes each LED look full brightness and multiply by the maximum number of LEDs that can be (visually!) 'on' at once. That might be close to 100A..

It applies no matter how you drive the LEDs (multiplexed or static).